# Did Vishnu ever use his mace Kaumodaki?

Tags: vishnu, weapon

He used the Chakra a lot and also his bow.  I can't think of an occasion when he used his mace either as himself or an avatar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Lord Vishnu used his Kaumodaki mace to kill a demon name Andhaka. The story is mentioned in [Devi Bhagavata, Book 5, Chapter 6](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk05ch06.htm).

> Wanting to kill Andhaka, Janârdana became infuriated, and, drawing his bow made of horn, call S'ârnga, shot at him arrows after arrows. The Dânava cut off all those arrows to pieces with his own mass of arrows. Then, becoming very angry, he shot fifty sharp arrows at Hari. Vâsudeva quickly made all those arrows useless and hurled Sudars'ana Chakra with thousand spokes on the Dânava with great violence. Andhaka thwarted this with his own discus and shouted aloud with such a great force that all the Devas became confused and confounded. Visnu's Chakra being baffled, the Devas became distressed with grief and the Dânavas got elated. **Seeing the Devas thus grieved, Visnu held aloft his Kaumodakî Gadâ (club) and came hurriedly before the Dânava. Hari struck then with his Gadâ on the Dânava's head whereon he fell senseless on the ground.**

Answer (score 5):

> Did Vishnu ever use his mace Kaumodaki?

**Yes.**

Following are some of the references of Purāṇas:

1. Lord Vishnu did use his mace as VarAha Avatara to kill the demon Hiranyaksha. It is mentioned in the **[3rd Canto Chapter 18 Verse 17 of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/18/17/)** :

   > ततश्च **गदयारातिं** दक्षिणस्यां भ्रुवि प्रभु: । 
   >   आजघ्ने स तु तां सौम्य गदया कोविदोऽहनत् ॥ १७ ॥
   >
   > *tataś ca **gadayārātiṁ**
   >
   >   dakṣiṇasyāṁ bhruvi prabhuḥ
   >
   >   ājaghne sa tu tāṁ saumya
   >
   >   gadayā kovido ’hanat*
   >
   > ***Translation***
   >
   > Then with ***His mace the Lord struck*** the enemy on the right of his brow, but since the demon was expert in fighting, O gentle Vidura, he protected himself by a maneuver of his own mace.
2. And from the same episode in [3rd Canto Chapter 19 and Verse 3 of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/19/3/)

   > सा हता तेन **गदया** विहता भगवत्करात् ।
   >   विघूर्णितापतद्रेजे तदद्भुतमिवाभवत् ॥ ३ ॥
   >
   > *sā hatā tena **gadayā**
   >
   >   vihatā bhagavat-karāt
   >
   >   vighūrṇitāpatad reje
   >
   >   tad adbhutam ivābhavat*
   >
   > ***Translation***
   >
   > Struck by the demon’s mace, however, the Lord’s mace slipped from His hand and looked splendid as it fell down whirling. This was miraculous, for the mace was blazing wonderfully.
3. Also in **[Viṣṇu-Purāṇa Ansh 5, Chapter 22, Verse-6](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp139.htm)** in the battle with Jarasandha, it is mentioned as:

   > अनन्तरं हरेश्शार्ङ्गं तूणौ चाक्षयसायकौ ।
   >   आकाशादागतौ विप्र तथा **कौमोदकी** गदा ।⁠।६।।
   >
   > हे विप्र! हरिके स्मरण करते ही उनका शार्ङ्ग धनुष, अक्षय बाणयुक्त दो तरकश और कौमोदकी नामकी गदा आकाशसे आकर उपस्थित हो गये ।।⁠६।।
   >
   > O Brahmana! Hari's Sharanga Bow with 2 inexhaustible quiver and his Kaumodaki mace came from the sky and stood before him.
4. Another from **[10th Canto Chapter 77 and Verse 20 of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/77/20/)**

   > इत्युक्त्वा भगवाञ्छाल्वं **गदया** भीमवेगया ।
   >   तताड जत्रौ संरब्ध: स चकम्पे वमन्नसृक् ॥ २० ॥
   >
   > *ity uktvā bhagavāñ chālvaṁ
   >
   >   **gadayā** bhīma-vegayā
   >
   >   tatāḍa jatrau saṁrabdhaḥ
   >
   >   sa cakampe vamann asṛk*
   >
   > ***Translation***
   >
   > Having said this, the furious Lord swung His **club** with frightening power and speed and hit Śālva on the collarbone, making him tremble and vomit blood.
5. Another from **[10th Canto Chapter 78 Verse 8 of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/78/8)**

   > गदयाभिहतोऽप्याजौ न चचाल यदूद्वह: ।
   >   कृष्णोऽपि तमहन् गुर्व्या **कौमोदक्या** स्तनान्तरे ॥ ८ ॥
   >
   > gadayābhihato ’py ājau
   >   na cacāla yadūdvahaḥ
   >   kṛṣṇo ’pi tam ahan gurvyā
   >   **kaumodakyā** stanāntare
   >
   > ***Translation***
   >
   > Although hit by Dantavakra’s club, Lord Kṛṣṇa, the deliverer of the Yadus, did not budge from His place on the battlefield. Rather, with His massive Kaumodakī club the Lord struck Dantavakra in the middle of his chest.

Answer (score 2):

The battle between Hirnayaksha and Varaha at the sea floor was fought with maces. I presume Varaha used His mace Kaumodaki. There is no mention of Varaha using the Sudarshana Chakra to kill Hiranyaksha in Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana and the description iss of Him armed with the conch, discus and mace.

Comment: citation please, from an undisputed mahapurana.

Answer (score 1):

Sri Varaha fought for Hundred years with Kaumodaki mace/club before using Chakra and  kicking Hiranyaksha dead by attacking his ear with his feet. Sri Krishna launched Kaumodaki on Salva which hit his neck and the magic empowered demon vomited blood. To break Salva's Saubha Airship into Pieces, Sri Krishna hurled Kaumodaki. Also to duel with Sri Jambavan for 20+ days and to kill Dantavakra on beach just after killing Salva

Answer (score 0):

Krishna fought against Jarasandha, and won, with the Vishnu weapons - discus, Saranga and Kaumodki, as per the Brahma Purana.

- While fighting with Jarasandha, all the Divine weapons of Vishnu (NARAYANA) reaches Sri Krishna from the skies, and with those Sri Krishna (an avatâra of Vishnu) defeats Jarasandha

> [Chapter 87](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216244.html) , Brahma Purāṇa
>
> 4. Surrounded by only a limited number of soldiers, the powerful Balarāma and Kṛṣṇa came out of their city and fought with the strong
>    soldiers.
> 5. Thereafter, O excellent sages, Balarāma and Kṛṣṇa of great strength thought of taking up their ancient weapons.
>
> - 6-8. **The discus, the śārṅga bow, two quivers with inexhaustible supply
>   of arrows and the iron club named Kaumodaki—all these came from the
>   firmament to those heroes.**
> - The ploughshare came into the hand of Balarāma from the sky. O
>   brahmins, it resembled the Saṃvarta fire. So also the Musala
>   (iron-club) called Sunanda came over to them.
> - **In the battle, the heroic lads Balarāma and Kṛṣṇa defeated the king of
>   Magadha together with his army.**
>
> English Translation by G.P. Bhatt