# Is Vishnu (or his Avataras) ever called "Narayana" while actively wielding a weapon and fighting?

Tags: vishnu, war

A search of battles fought with Kaumodaki doesn't seem to turn up the name

[Did Vishnu ever use his mace Kaumodaki?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24411/did-vishnu-ever-use-his-mace-kaumodaki)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, scriptures mention lord Vishnu as Narayana in active fight.
One occurrence is from [Harivamsha Purana - Book 1 - Harivamsa Parva - Chapter - 48](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/harivamsha-purana-dutt/d/doc485528.html) where lord Vishnu killed Kalanemi.

> 31. Although assailed by the highly powerful Daityas armed with various weapons the **lord Narayana remained unshaken in the battle like a mountain.**

> 34-35. Thereupon in that great encounter the Danavas began to strike Vishnu and Garuda with clods of earth, stones and thunder bolts. **When Narayana moved about in the battle field the gods chanted his glories**. "Glory unto you, O you of great arms, O destroyer of Madhu and Kaitava. With your nails you didst tear off Hiranyakasipu." **Thus eulogised by the deities Narayana rose up from the battle-field**. Considering Vishnu slain the king of Danavas blew his conch. The great Asuras began to play on the three sorts of Mridangas and dance in accompaniment with the music. It appeared that a great festivity was taking place at that time. Beholding Suparna wounded and his own body unscathed, Vaikuntha, with eyes reddened in anger, took up his discus.

> 65. **O Narayana, in this war you have freed the three worlds of the thorns** and therefore do you now confer upon the high-souled Sakra the prosperous kingdom over the three worlds".

Another occurrence is also from [Harivamsha Purana - Book 2 - Vishnu Parva - Chapter - 86](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/harivamsha-purana-dutt/d/doc485627.html) where lord Vishnu killed Nikumbha.

> 61-62. Hearing this Hari, the refuge of the pious and the protector of the world, said "So be it." And then saluting Mahadeva he discharged his discus Sudarshana, the destroyer of the Daitya race. **That discus, effulgent like the solar disc, discharged off Narayana’s hand, sundered Nikumbha’s head adorned with most beautiful ear-rings.**

Comment: Thanks for proving  my point.  NOT ONCE is Narayana spoken of as using a weapon, except in association with the active Vishnu or his other names who actually use weapons just about all the time..  Narayana, an advaitic notion has been grafted onto Vishnu stories and the inconsistency shows.  I'll bet Vishnu would fight often with Narayana never coming into the picture.

Comment: Please check the chapters I mentioned. And also the last quote "That discus, effulgent like the solar disc, discharged off Narayana’s hand, sundered Nikumbha’s head adorned with most beautiful ear-rings."

Comment: Hari discharged it (active voice) - Narayana is just an epithet of Hari - and note the passive role of Narayana - "the disc dicharged off his hand"

Comment: Your question is "Is Vishnu (or his Avataras) ever called "Narayana" while actively wielding a weapon and fighting?" So here Vishnu is called Narayana when fighting.

Answer (score 0):

First, An avatâra of Vishnu named Narayana (of the the famous Nara-Narayana rishi twins) is said to have fought several battles.

For instance -

#### 1. MAHABHARATA :

- In the Mahabharata, he's depicted fighting Shiva. Krishna recounts the famous fight between the two rishi incarnation of Nararayana (Vishnu) as thus -

> [Section CCCXLIII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826301.html), Mokshadharma Parva, Shanti Parva
>
> In days of yore, O Partha, I was, for some reason, born as the son of
> Dharma, O chief of Kuru’s race, and in consequence of such birth of
> mine I was celebrated under the name of Dharmaja. I took birth in two
> forms, viz., as Nara and Narayana. Riding on the vehicle that helps
> towards the performance of scriptural and other duties, I practised,
> in those two forms, undying austerities on the breast of
> Gandhamadana[23] At that time the great sacrifice of Daksha took
> place. Daksha, however, in that sacrifice of his, refused to give a
> share unto Rudra, O Bharata, of the sacrificial offerings. Urged by
> the sage Dadhichi, Rudra destroyed that sacrifice. He hurled a dart
> whose flames blazed up every moment. That dart, having consumed all
> the preparations of Daksha’s sacrifice, came with great force towards
> us (Nara and Narayana) at the retreat of Vadari. With great violence
> that dart then fell upon the chest of Narayana. Assailed by the energy
> of that dart, the hair on the head of Narayana became green. In fact,
> in consequence of this change in the hue of my hair I came to be
> called by the name of Munjakesa. **Driven off by an exclamation of
> Hun which Narayana uttered, the dart, its energy being lost, returned
> to Sankara’s hands. At this, Rudra became highly angry and as the
> result thereof he rushed towards the Rishis Nara and Narayana, endued
> with the puissance of severe austerities. Narayana then seized the
> rushing Rudra with his hand by the throat. Seized by Narayana, the
> lord of the universe, Rudra’s throat changed colour and became dark.
> From that time Rudra came to be called by the name of Sitikantha.**
>
> English Translation by K.M. Ganguli

---

#### 2. Devi Bhagvatam Purana :

- Here, the fight is depicted between, yet again, the Narayana Rishi, and the great devotee of Vishnu Prahalada., as follows -

> [Chapter 9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57173.html), Book 4, DeviBhagvatam purana
>
> - 43-44. Thus, then, when all the bows of Prahlāda were destroyed, the
>   Daitya Rājā took up Parigha (iron club), became enraged and threw it
>   on Nārāyana’s arm. **The powerful Bhagavān Nārāyana, seeing the dreadful
>   iron club, cut it asunder with nine arrows and pierced Prahlāda with
>   ten arrows.**
>
> .....
>
> 50. Thus for one thousand Deva years the terrible fight lasted between Prahlāda and Nārāyaṇa in that hermitage; and the whole universe was
>     struck with surprise.
>
> - 51-52. Then Gadādhara with yellow robes and four hands quickly came
>   there and called Prahlāda. The son of Hiraṇya Kaśipoo, Prahlāda,
>   seeing the Lord of Lakṣmi, four armed, Nārāyaṇa with lotus and disc in
>   His hands come there, bowed low, and, with folded hands, began to
>   speak to him with great devotion.
> - 53-54. O Deva of the Devas! You are the Lord of the universe and
>   devoted to your devotees. O Mādhava! I have fought for full one
>   hundred Deva years; still I have not not been able to defeat these
>   ascetics. I do not know why. I am surprised at it.
> - 55-56. Viṣṇu said :-- O Forgiving One! **These two Ṛṣis Nara Nārāyaṇa
>   are, the perfect ascetics, self controlled and born of my Amsas.
>   Therefore you have not been able to defeat them.** What wonder is
>   there! O king! Better go now to your Pātāla and keep your steadfast
>   devotion on me. O Intelligent one! Do not quarrel any more with these
>   two ascetics.

---

---

- Vishnu (NARAYANA) uses Kaumodki in the Tarakasura battle.

#### 3. In the Skanda Purāṇa

- Although, when using Kaumodki he's referred Janardana, but later in the same Chapter he's referred to as Narayana too.

> [Chapter 32](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc366018.html), Kaumārikā-khaṇḍa, Māheśvara-khaṇḍa
>
> 40. Janārdana who was quick in taking action, seized his (iron club) **Kaumodakī** and hurled it at the leader of the army. It smashed the
>     charioteer.
>
> ....
>
> 156. When this was averred (by Skanda) a loud sound (of applause) arose from the ranks of Heaven-dwellers. Some of them praised Guha and
>      some praised **Lord Nārāyaṇa.**

Slightly related excerpt from Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa itself again.

> [Chapter 36](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423604.html) -Setu-māhātmya, Brāhma-khaṇḍa
>
> Verse 3.1.36.99
>
> **गदा कौमोदकी नाम नारायणकरस्थिता** । 
> अपस्मारादिभूतानि नाशयत्येव सर्वदा ॥
> ९९ ॥
>
> 99. **The Iron Club named Kaumodakī held in Nārāyaṇa’s hand always destroys
>     the evil spirits of Apasmāra, etc. Similarly the Discus with sharp
>     edges burns his enemies**. The Conch too shall expel demons, ghosts,
>     etc.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

Comment: not a single instance where narayana (the God, not the rishi) actually fights.

Comment: You have added incarnations too, Multiple instances are written where Narayana Rishi (Who is Vishnu's incarnation) fights!! The name of the incarnation is Narayana only, what else do you expect in that case? Kindly, re-read the answer properly @SK

Comment: Narayana is a different concept that Vaishnavites merged into Vishnu Mahanarayana Upanishad “he (Narayana) is Brahma, Shiva, Hari (Vishnu), Indra, the imperishable, highest, self-ruler”  I am looking for evidence of the initial separation - I think Narayana never fights.  I can change the Q to moola forms plus purna avataras.